# C# user settings resets

Tags: c#, properties, io

I try to save a user-settings properties on my app,and it updates and work as long as i run the program from the same directory,but when i just change it's location,it seems like the properties reset.
This is my code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string user = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
        string pass = Properties.Settings.Default.password;
        Console.WriteLine(user);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to KeepOnGoing , lets sign-up.");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Remember,you may sign up only once! Once you'll sign up you get a unique account which cannot be made again!");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your new username : ");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your new Password : ");
            pass = Console.ReadLine();
            Properties.Settings.Default.username = user;
            Properties.Settings.Default.password = pass;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

As you can see i created a `if` condition to check if it the user fills the data in the first time,otherwise i'll have to display him the sign-up part.
How can i prevent the properties reset and make it common for the whole computer directories?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try save / load settings from ProgramData/<App Name> ?

Comment: @Uzzy what do you mean load settings from programdata?

Comment: Part of what determines the Settings file location is the path of the app.  You could manually save to a file in Users/AppData, to have one per user, but they can delete it to start over

Comment: @Slashy you use locations near .exe file. If you will save / load in a common location like ProgramData/<App Name> then you would solve the issue. see at System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx for instance

Comment: @Uzzy allright so you mean to save the user settins to a special folder? such as desktop?if so-how to change the properties location?and how can  i load it everytime from that specific location?

Comment: *do it manually* == create a file, open it, read it, close it

Comment: well . you can setup <setupConfigLocation><some path></setupConfigLocation> in appsetings.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are stored in [YourProgramName].exe.config. When you switch directories, make sure the *.exe.config file with your saved user-settings is also copied over to the new directory.